# I'm having a weird problem with my Ajax code. How can I solve this?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

[image: When I click on my edit button the first time then it populate into the city field and area field nicely. But when I clicked on the edit button second-time city field does not populate correctly.]

When I click on all of my edit buttons the first time then it populates into the city field and area field nicely. But when I clicked on the edit button a second time the city field does not populate. After refreshing its populate again with the same problem. I need help.

**City field code:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectCity">
  <option value="0" selected disabled>--- Select City ---</option>
       @foreach ($cities as $city)
       <option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->city_name }}</option>
       @endforeach
</select>
```

**My Ajax code:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#edit_area', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#addArea').hide();
                $('#updateArea').show();
                var area_id = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/edit-area/" + area_id,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status == 400) {
                            //some staff goes here
                        } else {
                            $('#area_id').val(area_id);
                            $('#areaName').val(response.area[0].area_name);
                            $('#selectCity').find("option:contains(" + response.area[0].city_name + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');//this works more better
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Any console error?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]